# Regex in Akeeba Backup exclude all hidden files

Tags: joomla-3.x, akeebabackup

I am struggling to find a regex for Akeeba Backup (3.11.0), that will exclude specific hidden files that start with ._ (dot underscore) in all directories of the website.
Have anyone ever done this?

Here what I have tried that is closer to what I want, among other regex, but they don't work.
 
    `#^\._#`  &  `[^\._]`

Comment: Try using `/^._/s`

Comment: nop - it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got the correct answer from Akeeba support. The regex that works in this case is :

```
#(^\.|/\.)_#
```

All credits go to Nicholas from Akeeba.

Comment: Just a small note, this could also be written more basically as `#(^|/)\._#`.  Match either from the beginning of the string or from a literal forward slash (anywhere in the string), followed immediately by a literal dot, followed by an underscore.

Answer (score 1):

I think it just uses `preg_match()` so I would try using a tool like [regex101](http://regex101.com/#pcre) with the `pcre` flavour to build your match pattern.

Have you tried with out the delimiters, i.e. something simple like `^\._`

Comment: I have tried without the delimiters. The ^\._ it doesn't work. However the \._ works but it will match all files that contain ._ in their filename.